# is there any better way to do this js code?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am making these panels to be resized to fit screen height as I click 'this' element. I feel like I hard coded those javascript, and I believe there must be better way. But couldn't really sort it out.

when one panel is clicked, its size is going to get bigger, and rest of pannels gonna get smaller

I would very much appreciate any suggestion of it.

I've tried making this function reusable, but then couldn't really come up with better solution as I am a begginer.

```
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
        const panelsArr = Array.from(panels);

        panelsArr.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click',getCurrentName))

        function getCurrentName(element) { 
            const panel1 = document.querySelector('.panel1');
            const panel2 = document.querySelector('.panel2');
            const panel3 = document.querySelector('.panel3');
            const panel4 = document.querySelector('.panel4');

            console.log(this);
            if(this) {

                this.classList.toggle('active');

                if(this === panel1) {

                panel2.classList.toggle('inactive');
                panel3.classList.toggle('inactive');
                panel4.classList.toggle('inactive');    
                } else if (this === panel2) {
                panel1.classList.toggle('inactive');
                panel3.classList.toggle('inactive');
                panel4.classList.toggle('inactive'); 

                } else if (this === panel3) {
                panel1.classList.toggle('inactive');
                panel2.classList.toggle('inactive');
                panel4.classList.toggle('inactive'); 

                } else if (this === panel4) {
                panel1.classList.toggle('inactive');
                panel2.classList.toggle('inactive');
                panel3.classList.toggle('inactive'); 
                }

            }

        }
```

```css
.panel {
    background-color: #002712;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .5rem rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    min-height: 22.5vh; 
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    line-height: 8rem;
    transition: 
    min-height .5s linear,
    font-size .2s linear .5s,
    line-height .2s linear .5s;
}

.panel1 { background-image: url("../images/steake.png"); }
.panel2 { background-image: url("../images/sundayRoast.png"); }
.panel3 { background-image: url("../images/image1(1).png"); }
.panel4 { background-image: url("../images/cannonbury.png"); }

.active { 
    min-height: 37vh;
    line-height: 15rem;
    font-size: 2.3rem;
}

.inactive { 
    min-height: 15vh; 
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
            <section class="intro">
                <div class="intro-panels">
                    <section class="panel panel1">
                        <p>most original,</p>
                    </section>
                    <section class="panel panel2">
                        <p>best beer,</p>
                    </section>
                    <section class="panel panel3">
                        <p>grilled food</p>
                    </section>
                    <section class="panel panel4">
                        <p>Islington</p>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
```

I expect simplified javascript code to achieve the same goal.

Here's how I've sorted it out by your answer. Thank you for your help guys.

```
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
        const panelsArr = Array.from(panels);

        panelsArr.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', getCurrentName))

        function getCurrentName(element) {
            if(this) {

                panelsArr.forEach(panel => panel.classList.toggle('inactive'));

                this.classList.toggle('inactive');
                this.classList.toggle('active');
            }

        }
```

Comment: This sounds like a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your code is wrong. `getCurrentName` use `event`, not `element`, and `this` can not be used in an `if`, Oou should read my complete response in one of the following posts. your `arrayArr` is useless, and my solution uses only one event listener for  all the 4 or N panels

Answer (score 0):

You could mark them all as inactive and re-mark the current one as active.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.panel')).forEach(element => {
  element.classList.remove('active');
  element.classList.add('inactive')
});
this.classList.remove('inactive');
this.classList.add('active');
```

You could also filter out `this` from the array, but it wouldn't change the outcome.

Comment: `Array.from()` is unnecessary here as `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a structure that provides a `forEach()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle `inactive` class on all class elements but undo it again on the target element:

```
    const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
    const panelsArr = Array.from(panels);

    panelsArr.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click',getCurrentName))

    function getCurrentName(element) { 
        console.log(this);
        if(this) {

            // Toggle inactive on all elements
            for (i = 0; i < panels.length; ++i) {
              panels[i].classList.toggle('inactive');
            }

            //But undo for selected element again
            this.classList.toggle('inactive');
            this.classList.toggle('active');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Event delegation

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  if(e.target.matches('.sizable')) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.sizable').forEach(div => {
      div.classList.remove('active');
      div.classList.add('inactive');
    });
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  }

});
```

```css
.sizable {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.inactive {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.active {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizable">Stuff</div>
<div class="sizable">Stuff</div>
<div class="sizable">Stuff</div>
<div class="sizable">Stuff</div>
<div class="sizable">Stuff</div>
<div class="sizable">Stuff</div>
```